# Libgdx Intellij gradle resolve error

Tags: macos, gradle, libgdx

I'm trying to import Libgdx gradle project to newest IntelliJ on mac osx, I have Resolve Error window with: "Please, use JDK instead of JRE for Gradle importer". 
I don't understand this message. What is wrong?

Greetings

Peter

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have correct JDK version specified for the Project and Gradle:

[image: Gradle JVM]

Answer (score 0):

1. check jdk path if it is not correct then please update it.

To change it I go to File -> Project Structure and try to find the JDK 1.6 location.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently running IntelliJ on Linux; the issue is that the Gradle importer needs the JDK rather than just the JRE to do its work.  You might be able to fix this just by selecting a JDK rather than a JRE in the Gradle JVM drop-down, but this won't work if you haven't already told IntelliJ about a JDK.

You can add a JDK by opening another project, then selecting File -> Project Structure -> Project SDK and clicking New.  In my case the SDK was installed in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8...  When you've added the JDK, you can re-open the original project and choose the new JDK in the Gradle JVM drop-down.  The installer should work then.

This doesn't feel like a good solution, in part because it relies on you having an existing project to open (or creating a new one!), but it seems to work.